# alternative to Uniformjs for styling select and check boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, widget, drop-down-menu

Uniformjs seems to be unmaintained now (last commit 2 years ago). Is there another **solid** javascript library that allows you to style select, radio and check boxes?

Comment: Check my own plugin http://code.google.com/p/idealforms/. It might be what you're lookin' for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap has custom buttons, select drop-downs and much more:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Answer (score 0):

Uniformjs is still being actively coded on github forks. 
This fork has been recently updated and contains most of the other recent contributions
https://github.com/fidian/uniform

Comment: The fork has not replaced the main project, if you know what I mean. For example `delayed_job` has two active forks.

Comment: The fork has been merged into pixelmatrix's branch (the main project) and I'm slowly working on bugs to get a version 2 release.